# Export .png transparent in PPT using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Code below does not account for group. Anyone please could fix this?

```
Sub EXPORT_PNG()
    Dim lheight As Long
    Dim lwidth As Long
        lwidth = 100
        lheight = 200
 ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Export "C:\New folder\test.png", ppShapeFormat ScaleWidth:=lwidth, ScaleHeight:=lheight
End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "does not account for group"

Comment: @SteveRindsberg it means above code work on single shape of object but when two or more shapes are grouped it won't work.

Comment: As is, the code won't even compile or run. Change ppShapeFormat to ppShapeFormatPNG.  I did that then ran it against a group of two  rectangles and it ran as expected. Try that change then if there's still a problem, let us know what you mean by "won't work".

Comment: Hello, @SteveRindsberg even if the code the works it can not exported as defined pixels. well thanks for help!

Comment: That's correct.  The scaling numbers don't represent pixels. See if these SO entries help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110931/shape-export-scalewidth-scaleheight-args  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333936/how-to-adjust-export-image-size-in-powerpoint-using-vba

Comment: It helps a lot. Thanks.